# Learning ExtJS, referenceerror issue

Tags: extjs, extjs4, referenceerror

I'm new to ExtJS.
I don't know why this code isn't working.
It gives me

> ReferenceError: Country is not defined

Here is the code:

```
Ext.define("Continent", {
extend: "Ext.data.Model",
fields: ["name"]
});
Ext.define("City", {
extend: "Ext.data.Model",
fields: ["name"]
});
Ext.define("CountryDetails", {
extend: "Ext.data.Model",
fields: ["id","population"],
});

Ext.define("Country", {
extend: "Ext.data.Model",
idProperty : "name",
fields: ["name", "capital"],
hasMany: [{ name: "cities", model: "City"}],
hasOne: [{model:"CountryDetails"}],
belongsTo: [{ model: "Continent"}],
proxy : {
    type : "memory",
    data : {
    country : {
        name : "France",
        capital : "Paris",
        countrydetails : {
            id : "cd101",
            population : 65436552
        },
        cities : [{name:"Lyon"},{name:"Avignon"}],
        continent : {
            name : "Europe"
        }
    }
},
reader : {
    type : "json",
    root : "country"
    }
}
});

Country.load("France",{
success : function(record){
    var continent = record.getContinent();
    console.log(continent.get("name"));
    var countryDetails = record.getCountryDetails();
    console.log(countryDetails.get("population"));
    var cities = record.cities();
    cities.each(function(city){
        console.log(city.get("name"));
    });
}
});
```

I copied from the book *Pratical ExtJS 4* and it doesn't work... I'm not happy with the author...

Comment: I guess you are missing a line like `var Country = Ext.create('Country');` or similar. `Ext.define` defines a "class", and `Ext.create` creates an instance.

Comment: @Alexander I tried but it gave me many error. Suposely it should work with only the model, I guess the author wouldn't miss on something so obvious such as a .create() .

Comment: As-is the code works as expected in Ext 4.x - you should try and reproduce your error in a [fiddle](http://fiddle.sencha.com).

Comment: I was able to reproduce it here https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/18m9

Comment: @alex9311 For me it gives me: Uncaught TypeError: record.getCountryDetails is not a function . Is it working correctly for you?

Comment: I get the same error, I think the getters are supposed to be automatically generated but apparently that isn't happening

Comment: Ok, thanks. This question is no longer relevant to me. Insted of doing Model.load() I use Store.load() which I believe it would work. Its interesting that we are all Alexanders :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working perfectly, check jsfiddle link https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1bsc

```
Ext.application({
name : 'Fiddle',

launch : function() {
    Ext.define("Continent", {
        extend: "Ext.data.Model",
        fields: ["name"]
    });
    Ext.define("City", {
        extend: "Ext.data.Model",
        fields: ["name"]
    });
    Ext.define("CountryDetails", {
        extend: "Ext.data.Model",
        fields: ["id", "population"],
    });
    Ext.define("Country", {
        extend: "Ext.data.Model",
        idProperty: "name",
        fields: ["name", "capital"],
        hasMany: [{
            name: "cities",
            model: "City"
        }],
        hasOne: [{
            model: "CountryDetails"
        }],
        belongsTo: [{
            model: "Continent"
        }],
        proxy: {
            type: "memory",
            data: {
                country: {
                    name: "France",
                    capital: "Paris",
                    countrydetails: {
                        id: "cd101",
                        population: 65436552
                    },
                    cities: [{
                        name: "Lyon"
                    }, {
                        name: "Avignon"
                    }],
                    continent: {
                        name: "Europe"
                    }
                }
            },
            reader: {
                type: "json",
                root: "country"
            }
        }
    });

    Country.load("France", {
        success: function(record) {
            var continent = record.getContinent();
            var countryDetails = record.getCountryDetails();

            document.write(countryDetails.get("population") + '<br />');

            var cities = record.cities();
            cities.each(function(city) {
                document.write(city.get("name") + '<br />');
            });
        }
    });
}
});
```